# Custom Filter on Dynamic Data Website

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I want to able to search on a column that is a foreign key to another table. I don't want to type in the ID (which is the foreign key). I want to search by name.

For example, you have a Product Table and a Manufacturer Table. On the Products gridview, I want to be able to search the Manufacturer Name - not Manufacturer Id. But the Products gridview has ProductID.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably put in your database type as tag or somewhere in the title or description

Answer (score 0):

If you create a foreign relationship between 2 tables, thwn **1st column in the table that is not in 'filtered' will be used as 'EntityName'**.

In my case I have:

- table Product that is referred by ProductSku table (Product.ProdId=ProductSku.ProdId);
- table ProductSku that is referred by SkuPrice table (ProductSku.SkuId=SkuPrice.SkuId);
- table ProductSku has following fields: SkuId, ProdId, PartName,...

and dynamic data page for 'SkuPrice' table instead of 'SkuId' field contains 'ProductSku' and value of ProductSku.PartName is displayed in this field.